# Adding text above legend using the `ggplot2` package in `R`

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following example code produces a given plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data=dat,
    aes(x=X, y=Y, ymin=lo, ymax=hi,
        shape=task, colour=task)) +
    geom_point(size=3, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
    geom_errorbar(width=0.12, linewidth=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.5)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17),
        labels=c('A', 'B')) +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette='Dark2',
        labels=c('A', 'B')) +
    scale_x_discrete('X',
        labels=c(1, 2, 3, 4)) +
    scale_y_continuous('Y', limits=c(6.0, 8.0),
        breaks=c(6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0)) +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title='Task:'),
        shape=guide_legend(title='Task:')) +
    ggtitle('Title') +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
    annotate(geom='text', x=1, y=8, label='1.0', color='black') +
    annotate(geom='text', x=2, y=8, label='0.93', color='black') +
    annotate(geom='text', x=3, y=8, label='0.95', color='black')
p
```

[image: Fig-1]

How can I add some text at the place marked in red?
Thanks!

Comment: Can we have a sample of `dat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to turn clipping off and use a custom annotation:

```r
p + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob("My text", x = 1.05, y = 0.95))
```

[image]

Here, the x and y co-ordinates are relative to the plotting panel (i.e. the gray rectangle), so that x = 0 is the left edge and x = 1 is the right edge. A value of 1.05 will therefore be beyond the right edge of the plotting panel.

---

**Data used (inferred approximately from plot in question)**

```r
dat <- data.frame(X = as.character(rep(1:4, each = 2)), 
           Y = c(6.3, 6.6, 6.4, 6.7, 6.5, 6.8, 6.6, 6.8),
           lo = c(6.1, 6.4, 6.2, 6.5, 6.3, 6.6, 6.4, 6.6),
           hi = c(6.5, 6.8, 6.6, 6.9, 6.7, 7, 6.8, 7),
           task = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 4))
```

Comment: Thanks [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron), this looks fairly straightforward. Is there a way to make the font slightly smaller/bigger?

Comment: @striatum yes, add `gp = grid::gpar(size = 14)` inside `textGrob`

Comment: How is this use of `annotation_custom` that different from `annotate(.)`? This seems effectively the same as my earlier answer.

Comment: @r2evans there's not a huge difference, and I did upvote your answer because they are reasonable approaches.(Incidentally I would have answered earlier but spent considerable time reverse-engineering the data to recreate the OP's plot). I guess the main difference is that in the `annotate` case you are losing the ability to use `hjust` and `vjust` . For example, left or centre aligning multi-line text won't work. From that perspective I think `annotation_custom` is a better general solution. Happy to have any flaws in that logic corrected though.

Comment: I'm not an aficionado in either `*annotat*` function, tbh. I don't understand your assertion about losing `hjust`/`vjust`, are you saying that `annotation_custom(..)` does not support their use? (And reverse-engineering data can always be a time-sink :-)

Comment: @r2evans I meant that in `annotate`, you are using `hjust` and `vjust` to help control the position of the text rather than using it for alignment. On the contrary, `annotation_custom` allows you to position the grob anywhere you like using npc co-ordinates _and_ still use hjust and vjust (via gpar). Thus, it would be trivial to centre-align multi-line text with `annotation_custom`, but in the `annotate` version the text will be strictly left-aligned due to the vjust of 0.

Comment: @r2evans with regards to reverse-engineering data, it _is_ a time sink but usually generates a more satisfying answer for the OP. It's a gamble though, because during the time it takes, someone may post an answer similar to the one you are investing time in, and that may lead to either scrapping your answer or posting an answer that isn't sufficiently different. This one was a close call, and I thought on balance it probably added something, but it's not a straightforward one.

Answer (score 2):

Two options come to mind:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x=Inf, y=Inf, label="QUUX", hjust=0, vjust=1) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = max, labels = \(z) "QUUX")) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank())
```

[image]